# Sorting Results efficiently by non mapped/searchable Object properties

Tags: elasticsearch

In my current index called `items` I have previously sorted the results of my queries by some property values of a specifiy object property, lets call this property just `oprop`. After I have realized, that with each new key in `oprop` the total number of used fields on the `items` index increased, I had to change the mapping on the index. So I set `oprop`'s mapping to `dynamic : false`, so the keys of `oprop` are not searchable anymore (not indexed).

Now in some of my queries I need to sort the results on the items index by the values of `oprop` keys. I don't know how ElasticSearch still can give me the possibility to sort on these key values.

Do I need to use scripts for sorting? Do I have access on non indexed data when using scripts?

Somehow I don't think that this is a good approach and I think that in long term I will run into performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could use scripts for sorting, since the data will be stored in the `_source` field, but that should probably be a last resort. If you know which fields need to be sortable, you could just add those to the mapping, and keep `oprop` as a non dynamic field otherwise?

```
"properties": {
    "oprop": {
        "dynamic": false,
        "properties": {
            "sortable_key_1": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "sortable_key_2": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly the sortable keys are ids and since my search index is globaly used by mutliple shops, the total_fields just add up with every new key (id) and every new shop. Regarding your answer:  Does this mean, that I can run (sorting) scripts on the _source field ?

Comment: Upon further inspection, I'm not sure you can. While you have access to the [current document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-sort-context.html), I'm not convinced that actually includes the `_source`. Have you considered storing your ids in a property of a [nested object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html), and then adding what ever it is you need to sort on as a second property? Otherwise I'm not sure what you want to do is possible.